# Cannot boot to Windows after removing Ubuntu (dualboot)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, grub2

-Had dualboot windows + ubuntu, microsoft surfacebook

-Removed the partition that ubuntu resided on inside the Windows Disk Manager tool.

-Restarted, and found that I could not boot into Windows. Instead, I am send to the GNU GRUB V2 screen.

I have tried to run windows repair from a USB (I can get into my BIOS devices and select my USB) and I can see the USB emitting some sort of light, indicating activity. Microsoft surfacebook logo comes up, flashes a few times, then re-appears. Proceeds to GRUB v2 without ever booting into the USB.

This happens with different USBS, and with bootable Windows/Ubuntu images. These work fine on my other computer, and are indeed bootable.

Any ideas? My computer is practically useless at this point.

Running the `ls` command provides this output:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1, gpt1)
```

I have absolutely no idea which one of these is the USB, and as I understand it the next step here would be to try to boot into the USB from the GRUB GNU v2 commandline.

Comment: This is off-topic here because it's about general software, not programming. It's a reasonable question otherwise, though, so I'm voting to migrate it to Super User.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that you can flag your post for moderator attention if you'd like them to migrate it. (People with 3000+ reputation can vote to migrate to certain sites, but it takes several votes to do so).

Comment: If you have access to a bootable Ubuntu USB drive you can temporarily fix this issue by following this, works every time I goof my dual boot https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Try this https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/storage-files-and-folders/boot-surface-from-usb-recovery-device?os=windows-10&=undefined maybe you're flash should be uefi and etc. @mdobrenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to have Windows rebuild your boot sector.  This is done by booting the install disk and selecting repair.

The instructions can be found in this article:

[Repair Windows BCD - Windows 10/8.1/7/Vista](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html)

Comment: I cannot boot to the USB... so I can't run disk repair

Comment: Then you might want to use Rufus to make it an .ISO file, then CDburnerXP to put it on a DVD.